# How can I extract HTML from a URL that requires JavaScript?

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to extract the raw HTML from a page that requires JavaScript (with the ultimate goal of extracting just the plain text). Unfortunately, simple `get` requests return HTML specifying the need for a browser running JS. Example:

```
> html = open('https://www.medicare.gov/Publications/').read
"<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<!--[if lt IE 8]><html class=\"no-js oldIE\" lang=\"en-US\"><![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE 8]><html class=\"no-js lt-ie9\" lang=\"en-US\"><![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE 9]><html class=\"no-js ie9\" lang=\"en-US\"><![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE 11]>\n<style>\nbody{\ndisplay:none;\n}\n</style>\n<![endif]-->\n<!--[if (gt IE )|!(IE)]><!-->\n<html lang=\"en-US\" class=\"no-js not-ie\">\n    <!--<![endif]-->\n    <head>\n        <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n        <!--<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\">-->\n        <title>Publications</title>...
<body>\n        <div class=\"wrapper sl-translate\">\n            <div class=\"needCSS hidden\">\n                This application is not fully accessible to users whose browsers do not support or have Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) disabled. For a more optimal experience viewing this application, please enable CSS in your browser and refresh the page.\n            </div>\n            <!--<p class=\"browsehappy\">\n                Your browser is out of date  or not supported. Please visit <a href=\"http://browsehappy.com/\">browse happy</a> to upgrade to a better supported, modern browser.\n            </p>-->\n            <div class=\"js-off-message\">\n                <noscript>\n                The page could not be loaded. This application currently does not support browsers with \"JavaScript\" disabled. Please enable JavaScript and refresh the page to view this application.\n                </noscript>"
```

I've tried tricking the page into thinking I'm using a browser with JS, but (shocker), that didn't work either:

```
html = = HTTP.headers(user_agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36").follow.get(url).to_s
```

Is there any trick to extracting the static HTML from a JS-driven page like https://www.medicare.gov/hospicecompare/?

Comment: you'll have to use a headless browser

Comment: The only way to get JavaScript to run is to have a JavaScript runtime involved. Tools like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org) or [Phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org) can do this.

Comment: Thanks, I think these comments have pointed me in the right direction. I'm trying the flow described in https://readysteadycode.com/howto-scrape-websites-with-ruby-and-headless-chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments suggesting I use a headless browser, and the approach described in https://readysteadycode.com/howto-scrape-websites-with-ruby-and-headless-chrome, I was able to extract the HTML and plain text using the following:

**Install [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/)**

```
$ brew install chromedriver
```

**Install [selenium-webdriver](https://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver) gem**

```
$ gem install selenium-webdriver
```

**Get webpage**

```
> require 'selenium-webdriver'
> options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(args: ['headless'])
> driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, options: options)
> driver.get 'https://www.medicare.gov/hospicecompare/'
```

**Extract HTML**

```
> driver.find_element(css: 'html').attribute('innerHTML')
```

**Extract Plain Text**

```
> driver.find_element(css: 'html').text
```

**References**

https://readysteadycode.com/howto-scrape-websites-with-ruby-and-headless-chrome
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings